# Profile link invalid error on account deletion form

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

[image: account deletion request]

I filled out the form to request my account be deleted as you can see, but for some reason my profile URL is being indicated as invalid. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: That is a link to your overall account which isn't a valid option on site profile deletion. Use https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/359672/will-njundong for deleting your account from this site and then repeat the process by clicking contact us on every site you want to delete your profile while providing the link to your user profile on that particular site. You can't delete multiple site profiles in one go. It needs multiple steps on purpose.

Comment: I have edited the accepted answer on that dupe to cover for the error you got.